# Building variations of nested case classes

Tags: scala, case-class

So I got something like this:

```
abstract class Term
case class App(f:Term,x:Term) extends Term
case class Var(s:String) extends Term
case class Amb(a:Term, b:Term) extends Term //ambiguity
```

And a Term may look like this:

```
App(Var(f),Amb(Var(x),Amb(Var(y),Var(z))))
```

So what I need is all variations that are indicated by the Amb class.
This is used to represent a ambiguous parse forest and I want to type check each possible variation and select the right one.
In this example I would need:

```
App(Var(f),Var(x))
App(Var(f),Var(y))
App(Var(f),Var(z))
```

Whats the best way to create these variations in scala? 
Efficiency would be nice, but is not really requirement. 
If possible I like to refrain from using reflection.

Comment: Note that you might want to represent the fact that some expressions are deterministic and some aren't in the type system (so that for example you don't have to worry about matching on `Amb` after you've performed this operation). Here's [a quick sketch](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/6955c190f086d96c3c0e) of what this might look like.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but I already have a fairly large abstract syntax, and that would a make it huge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala provides pattern matching solve these kinds of problems. A solution would look like:

```
def matcher(term: Term): List[Term] = {
  term match {
    case Amb(a, b) => matcher(a) ++ matcher(b)
    case App(a, b) => for { va <- matcher(a); vb <- matcher(b) } yield App(va, vb)
    case v: Var    => List(v)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this pretty cleanly with a recursive function that traverses the tree and expands ambiguities:

```
sealed trait Term
case class App(f: Term, x: Term) extends Term
case class Var(s: String) extends Term
case class Amb(a: Term, b: Term) extends Term

def det(term: Term): Stream[Term] = term match {
  case v: Var    => Stream(v)
  case App(f, x) => det(f).flatMap(detf => det(x).map(App(detf, _)))
  case Amb(a, b) => det(a) ++ det(b)
}
```

Note that I'm using a sealed trait instead of an abstract class in order to take advantage of the compiler's ability to check exhaustivity.

It works as expected:

```
scala> val app = App(Var("f"), Amb(Var("x"), Amb(Var("y"), Var("z"))))
app: App = App(Var(f),Amb(Var(x),Amb(Var(y),Var(z))))

scala> det(app) foreach println
App(Var(f),Var(x))
App(Var(f),Var(y))
App(Var(f),Var(z))
```

If you can change the `Term` API, you could more or less equivalently add a `def det: Stream[Term]` method there.

Answer (score 0):

Since my abstract syntax is fairly large (and I have multiple) and I tried my luck with Kiama.
So here is the version Travis Brown and Mark posted with Kiama.

Its not pretty, but I hope it works. Comments are welcome.

```
  def disambiguateRule: Strategy = rule {
    case Amb(a: Term, b: Term) =>
      rewrite(disambiguateRule)(a).asInstanceOf[List[_]] ++
      rewrite(disambiguateRule)(b).asInstanceOf[List[_]]
    case x => 
      val ch = getChildren(x)
      if(ch.isEmpty) {
        List(x)
      }
      else {
        val chdis = ch.map({ rewrite(disambiguateRule)(_) }) // get all disambiguate children
        //create all combinations of the disambiguated children
        val p = combinations(chdis.asInstanceOf[List[List[AnyRef]]]) 
        //use dup from Kiama to recreate the term with every combination
        val xs = for { newchildren <- p } yield dup(x.asInstanceOf[Product], newchildren.toArray)
        xs
      }
  }

  def combinations(ll: List[List[AnyRef]]): List[List[AnyRef]] = ll match {
    case Nil      => Nil
    case x :: Nil => x.map { List(_) }
    case x :: xs  => combinations(xs).flatMap({ ys => x.map({ xx => xx :: ys }) })
  }

  def getChildren(x: Any): List[Any] = {
    val l = new ListBuffer[Any]()
    all(queryf {
      case a => l += a
    })(x)
    l.toList
  }
```